# What's the simplest way of doing an auto suggest textfield in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I've googled a few scripts, but they're a little bit too complicated. I just want a simple solution. I have an array with some data (20 strings) and a textfield.

Comment: Have you seen jquery autocompleter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the Autocomplete offering from jQuery UI (http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/). It supports various data sources including local arrays.

Answer (score 0):

[jQuery autocomplete](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/autocomplete) is very easy to use and does the job.

[TagDragon](http://www.s3maphor3.org/tagdragon/) also seems cool, haven't used it personally though.